# How can I use same column twice?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have table which has two date time format.

```
fromDate (e.g) 2013-05-20 13:00:00
toDate  (e.g) 2013-05-20 15:00:00
```

I want to show data such as

```
date      |from |to
2013/5/20 |13:00|15:00
```

So I made this source code

```
public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('fromDate',null,array('label' => 'Date','format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
        ->add('fromDate',null,array('label' => 'from','format' => 'HH:mm:ss'))
        ->add('toDate',null,array('label' => 'to','date_format' => 'HH:mm:ss'))
```

but it shows.

> Unknown or duplicate field name in list mapper. Field name should be either of FieldDescriptionInterface interface or string. Names should be unique.

How can I use same column twice?
or 
How can I make it for this purpose?

Comment: Why not using, for example, `date`, `fromTime` and `toTime`?

Comment: Or `datetime` for `fromDate` and `time` for `toDate` with a simple processing of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default this isn't possible in the sonata admin bundle.

You have 2 choices...:

1. Create both fields in your entity (fromDate and fromTime) and use those
2. Rewrite it yourself to a custom view

Comment: Just to expand on the #1 solution, you do not necessarily need to create two different properties or two different fields in the database. You can have one field, fromDate, and create a getter method `getFromTime()` to return the fromDate property and format each field accordingly.